# Runtime Error: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (16x756900 and 3048516x30)

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, torch

How can I solve this problem?

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,8,11, padding=0) # in_channel, out_channel, kernel size
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2) # kernel_size, stride
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(8, 36, 5, padding=0)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(36*291*291, 30) # in_features, out_features
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(30, 20)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(20, 10)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

I wrote my code like this, but I got `"Runtime Error: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied".`

The input shape is:`'torch.Size([3,600,600])'` ,with 3 channels.
Please help me!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

756900
Just change the model definition, the output shape of your last convolution layer does not have the shape `36x291x291`. Just change the model definition to:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,8,11, padding=0) # in_channel, out_channel, kernel size
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2) # kernel_size, stride
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(8, 36, 5, padding=0)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(756900, 30) # in_features, out_features
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(30, 20)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(20, 10)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

Tried the same with your input size, and it works.

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thanks! um.. but, can you explain me how did you get the value 36*291*291?

Comment: Hey, sure. So the last convolution block has 36 output channels, which is where we get the 36 from. Since we provide a square shaped input, our width and height remains same after every convolution or maxpool operation. We can then use the formula provided in the shape section [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) to calculate the output shape for convolution. Using them I figured the input shape for the linear layer.